# Domain filter with '&' doesn't work in openerp7

Tags: odoo

Below is what i need to do

```
(Condition A and Condition B) or Condition C

(partner_id = partner_id **and** user_ids = context.get(uid)) **or** userid = 1
```

The possible domain filters i've tried are

```
domain="['|',('user_ids','=',1),'&',('partner_id','=',partner_id),('user_ids','=',context.get('uid'))]"

domain="['|','&',('partner_id','=',partner_id),('user_ids','=',context.get('uid')),('user_ids','=',1)]"
```

Nothing works out and the error i get is below

```
 File "D:\workspace\Techtalk\openerp\modules\loading.py", line 76, in <lambda>
   load_data = lambda *args: _load_data(cr, *args, kind='data')
 File "D:\workspace\Techtalk\openerp\modules\loading.py", line 124, in _load_data
   tools.convert_xml_import(cr, module_name, fp, idref, mode, noupdate, report)
 File "D:\workspace\Techtalk\openerp\tools\convert.py", line 941, in convert_xml_import
   doc = etree.parse(xmlfile)
 File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 2698, in lxml.etree.parse (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:49590)
 File "parser.pxi", line 1513, in lxml.etree._parseDocument (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:71423)
 File "parser.pxi", line 1543, in lxml.etree._parseFilelikeDocument (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:71733)
 File "parser.pxi", line 1426, in lxml.etree._parseDocFromFilelike (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:70648)
 File "parser.pxi", line 997, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseDocFromFilelike (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:67944)
 File "parser.pxi", line 539, in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:63820)
 File "parser.pxi", line 625, in lxml.etree._handleParseResult (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:64741)
 File "parser.pxi", line 565, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:64084)
XMLSyntaxError: xmlParseEntityRef: no name, line 144, column 12
```

Links i've refered are

http://help.openerp.com/question/2170/domain-notation-using-multiple-and-nested-and/

[OpenERP ver 7 Domain filter with more conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16276155/openerp-ver-7-domain-filter-with-more-conditions)

**Additional Notes**
I could not find a single domain filter with & operator in openerp source.

Am i missing something? Kindly suggest. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 4):

The error message suggests that your XML contains an invalid entity, i.e. a bare ampersand `&` character. As it is a predefined XML entity, you must escape it as `&amp;`.

The reason why you may not find many domain using `&` in the OpenERP source code is because the `AND (&)` operator is the default one, so you can omit it entirely in most cases. And that's convenient because of the escaping problem.
Still, it may be necessary when you combine OR/AND operators, so you can find examples in advanced security rules, which also use the same domain syntax, such as [here](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~openerp/openobject-addons/7.0/view/head:/mail/security/mail_security.xml#L10).

In general if you want `(A and B) or C` you can indeed write it as:

```
   ['|',C,'&',A,B]
```

which means your XML file should contain:

```
   ['|',C,'&amp;',A,B]
```